# Use my static IP in a different country

Tags: static-ip

Let’s assume that I have a static IP in X country, and I want use this static IP in Y country by using the Ethernet port out of laptop to be connected to a device require the same static IP of X country.

Let’s say laptop 1 in X country is connected with a static IP, while laptop 2 is connected with a Wi-Fi network in Y country, now I want to use the Ethernet port of laptop to feed my device with the Internet coming from X country.

Comment: You need a VPN on Laptop 1.

Comment: Is this static IP used on your computer or is it given by your ISP (meaning it's your router's external IP on the Internet)?

Comment: @harrymc, thank you for your replay, it is given by my ISP

Comment: @davidpostill, thank you for your replay, can you describe the all procedure please?

Comment: could teamviewer help me with this when enable the VPN option?

Comment: Teamviewer would not help you with a VPN. You might want to look to OpenVPN.

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer:** IP X can only work on ISP X. You will need to have laptop Y
go through laptop X. The easiest solution is to install a VPN server
on laptop X for use by laptop Y.

**Long answer:**

Normally this cannot work, since the IP address you got from ISP X is allocated and served only by ISP X.  ISP X in turn routes the IPs to the appropriate routers and end users.

(In order for an IP address to be connected through 2 or more providers, there are a number of criteria which need to be met, and which are outside the scope of most home users/small businesses.  These include: A minimum of a Class C - ie a range 256 IP addresses or more, an agreement between providers to advertise this traffic using a common protocol, and a routing setup on your side to handle this type of routing.  This is almost always done using [BGP](http://www.enterprisenetworkingplanet.com/netsp/article.php/3615896/Networking-101-Understanding-BGP-Routing.htm), and will additionally require another resource called an AS number).

An additional limitation is that most ISP's do ingress and egress filtering, meaning that if traffic which should come from one of their IP addresses comes from an external interface it is dropped, likewise, traffic leaving an external interface is not from an IP address they control the traffic is also dropped.   There are a number of reasons for this, but most prominently DoS protection and protection against theft of service.

You may install on laptop X a VPN server or IP tunnel as well as a NAT gateway, then connect to it from laptop Y and set a default gateway on laptop X out via the VPN/tunnel. This will allow traffic to be directed out laptop X via laptop Y, and allow it to return back.

This is quite viable, but will have the effect of slowing down communications, both because of doubling up on the amount of bandwidth used, and the additional latency caused by shunting the traffic through the tunnel.  It is also not trivial to set up.

You may also use a screen-sharing application such as
[TeamViewer](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/),
which is a very simple solution that lets laptop Y use laptop X as if you were logged on to it. It acts similar to a VPN server, but with a very simple setup that doesn't require any prior knowledge.
Displaying the whole screen of laptop X on laptop Y may be somewhat slow
internationally, but the TeamViewer website supplies some advice about
optimizing it, such as reducing the screen quality.

Comment: could tell me how to set it up please? i see that team viewer application provide VPN connection, can it be useful in my case here, many thanks for your time :), appreciated, the internet speed is not a major issue here.

Comment: Added some info about TeamViewer

Comment: thanks, but sharing screen is not the idea here, the idea is to share the internet by using the Ethernet cable!

Comment: That needs a VPN server on laptop X. There exists much documentation on the subject, for example [How to Create a VPN Server on Your Windows Computer Without Installing Any Software](https://www.howtogeek.com/135996/how-to-create-a-vpn-server-on-your-windows-computer-without-installing-any-software/).

Comment: Sorry for the downvote  but your paragraph on DNS is wrong - DNS has nothing to do with IP address routing. (It also ignores things like BGP and routing the same address range via.l multiple paths - which would.not be a problem except that your answer implies DNS and geoIP is involved) The bit on GeoIP is also highly questionable - the controlling bodies like RIPE, APNIC, ARON, AFRINIC etc are regional,  but not country specific/limited.

Comment: @davidgo: Why did I write "DNS" when I meant "Gateway Protocol"? Fixed that.

Comment: Terribly sorry, but this is still not really corrrect. IP ranges are not registered to servers - BGP handle routing advertisements which is why occassionally a bad player can redirect a swathe of Internet traffic. IP and routers have no concept of ISP only network ranges.  (Your conclusion - use a VPN is the.most practical solution - although you could get away with a simple tunnel)

Comment: @davidgo: What phrasing would you accept (you may also directly update my answer)? Gateway Protocol (Border Gateway Protocol) *is* BGP. If a simple false advertisement was enough, VPN companies wouldn't need a VPN server placed in the target country - all they would need to do is to give out an IP address and advertise it. Redirecting Internet traffic AFAIK is done by advertising false routes with very low metrics.

Comment: @harrymc - I've edited it fairly extensively - please have a look that you are happy with it.  A false advertisement could be enough if there were no protections against them. Redirecting Internet traffic is not done with low metrics, rather its done (from memory, I never became strong with BGP) by advertising shorter paths and higher "local prefs" - this is different to static routing -  and/or more specific routes.

Comment: @davidgo: I have no problem with your edits, except that I think the answer has now become a bit too much of a technical study and harder for a non-technical person to get the main point. I'm not sure that the poster will now understand what is his best and simplest route, a VPN server, since so many directions are outlined that require study.

Comment: I agree. Feel free to remove.the extaneous.information - much of what I put in (second second and third paragraphs - were an attempt to both be accurate and match the level of specificity I felt your  post had. )

Comment: @davidgo: No problem, our comments contain the gist of it.